# how to export function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am new in nodejs,i need to export function in nodejs 
**db_function.js** file

```
var mysql = require('mysql'); 
var config  = require('./config.js');
var con = config.conn;

exports.is_valid_IP = {
 function(IP,callback)
  {
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query("SELECT * FROM server_master", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(result);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

**app.js** file

```
  app.get('/test',function(req,res){
  var IP = 1;
  db.is_valid_IP(IP,function(result){
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

It Show error **Cannot call method 'connect' of undefined**

Comment: You export correctly. `con` is undefined in your `db_function.js`

Comment: i declared 
**var con = config.conn;**

Comment: And it didn't occur to you that `con` is probably `undefined`?

Comment: @MaheshJagdale I trust what Javascript says. Can you show us your entire `db_function`? Maybeyou declare con too late, and JS already tries to access it

Comment: con is declared in app.js, yet you try to access it in db_function.js. Even if you call your function in app.js, javascript still (thankfully) maintains the correct context for code evaluation and execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me sum up the comments:

You export correctly. That's not where your problem lies

The issue occurs due to the fact that, in `db_function.js`, `con` is not defined.

Even if you declare it in `app.js`, javascript will correctly isolate the two contexts (`app.js` from `db_function.js`).

We talk about different files here, but the context preservation can occur even in the same files

```
var functionOne = function(){
   var con = 1;
}
console.log(con) // undefined err, because con is declared inside the function
```

even if you call the function

```
var functionOne = function(){
   var con = 1;
}
functionOne();
console.log(con) // undefined err, because con is long gone as soon as function returns
```

`con` will live only until the function returns.

if  you want to tell `is_valid_IP` what connection to use, you can simply update your code as follows:

*db_function.js file*

```
exports.is_valid_IP = {
 function(IP,con,callback)
  {
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query("SELECT * FROM server_master", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(result);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

And then use it in app.js file as follows:

```
app.get('/test',function(req,res){
  var IP = 1;
  db.is_valid_IP(IP,con,function(result){
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: any other way..?

Comment: yes, give `is_valid_IP` function your connection, updating answer

Answer (score 5):

You can export like this:

```
enter code here
var funName = function() {
}
module.exports = funName;
```

Comment: Weird how this answer got 2 upvotes and is not even answering the question

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the issue, as the title of the question suggests, "how to export function in nodejs". If we only consider how to export function in Node.js, we can do as below:

./db_function.js (We export function isValidIp):

```
'use strict';

module.exports.isValidIp = function(ip, callback) {
    console.log("Check if IP is valid.");
    callback();
};
```

./app.js

```
'use strict';

var db = require('./db_function');
// require() returns the object that module.exports references

db.isValidIp('127.0.0.1', function(){
    console.log('Called back.');
});
```

Run it with command `node app.js`, you'll get:

```
Check if IP is valid.
Called back.
```

**One caveat**

./db_function.js (This version does not work):

```
'use strict';

exports = { 
    isValidIp: function(ip, callback) {
        console.log("Check if IP is valid.");
        callback();
    }
};
```

You'll get TypeError:

```
TypeError: db.isValidIp is not a function
```

That is because require() return module.exports, rather than exports. exports is just a shorthand of module.exports. If you point exports to a different object, you should update module.exports as well. The following version will work:

```
'use strict';

exports = { 
    isValidIp: function(ip, callback) {
        console.log("Check if IP is valid.");
        callback();
    }
};

module.exports = exports;
```

Comment: what if other way around: update module.exports, but not export ?